# Ocultar barra de tareas y de navegación en Android

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Android Studio y mediante código quité lo que es la barra de tareas y la barra de navegación que ciertos teléfonos tienen. Mi problema es que cuando se abre un cuadro de dialogo (`AlertDialog`) éstos aparecen y ya no se quitan hasta que cambia el layout. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Este es el código que tengo en el `onCreate()` para quitar estas barras.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions =   View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: podrias subir una imagen de como se veria cuando se pone el alert dialog y en que activity?

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias! Es justo lo que necesitaba para solucionar un tema en un diseño que estoy realizando

Answer (score 0):

Copia y pega el siguiente código en el activity que quieras que se oculten las barras,
esto hará que estas se oculten automaticamente tras hacer cualquier acción.

```
//código
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY     
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```